# Change master page for all sites

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, master-pages

I have a new master which has to be applied on all of my sites.
But I don't know to change the content of my odler master page in database (for all sites) via Powershell. I know how iterate my sites and modify the url of the master page, but me I just want to change the CONTENT of my master page.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Why not Use SharePoint designer. Using designer one Can change the code of master pages also. But the check is you should have the highest site privileges to the entire site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work. This adds to all Farm your master page.

```
foreach($webApp in (Get-SPWebApplication))
  foreach($site in $webApp.Sites)

  # check compatibility level -> 14 if SP2010, 15 if SP2013
  if ($site.CompatibilityLevel –eq 15) 
    foreach ($web in $site.AllWebs)
      if ($web.Exists)
        $web.SiteLogoUrl = "/SiteAssets/logo.png"
        $web.SiteLogoDescription = "My PowerShell Site"
        $web.MasterUrl = "/_catalogs/masterpages/seattle.master"
        $web.CustomMasterUrl = "/_catalogs/masterpages/seattle.master"

$web.Update()

$web.Dispose()
$site.Dispose()
```

Comment: Hello! Yes, I know how to do with Sharepoint Designer, but my goal is to do with Powershell ;'(

Comment: Hello Storm. When do you upload the new content of the master? That's is issue. In your code, you are pointing a new link to access to the new master page but how you put the master page at this link for all websites?

Comment: i would prefer you google a bit and you will find tons of answers on that. For example http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/17624/upload-master-page-using-powershell

Comment: Thanks a lot for this link, STORM!